# Jquery find data element

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have following code:

```
<div id="mainMenuInternalMyProfile" class="mainMenuInternalTab" data-pagename="myprofile">
  <div class="mainMenuInternalTabClickable">&nbsp;</div>
    <h4 class="mainMenuInternalTitle">MY PROFILE</h4>
    <img src="images/main-menu-divider.png" class="mainMenuBackGroundDivider" alt="Dating Internal Menu Background Divider">
    <img src="images/main-menu-selected.png" class="mainMenuBackSelected mainMenuBackSelectedOption" alt="Dating Internal Menu Selected">
  </div>
```

In the first line you can see the `data-pagename="myprofile"` line. I have a number of HTML chucks of code like this with different `data-pagename` values.

I need to be able to locate the data value that matches then one on hand - lets same 'home' or 'myprofile' and then make some CSS changes. I've tried the following:

```
var element = $('div.mainMenuInternalTab').find("[data-pagename='" + urlType + "']");
element.css({'color': '#000000','z-index':'100'});
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Can I use element like this?

I'm using find on `$('div.mainMenuInternalTab')` but there are several of these classes - should I use a higher up DIV with ID?

any advise would be great - can give more info if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this

```
$('div.mainMenuInternalTab').each(function() {
  var element = $(this).find("[data-pagename='" + urlType + "']");
  element.css({'color': '#000000','z-index':'100'});
}
```

or perhaps create a classname for the color and zIndex:

```
element.toggleclass("black");
```

**UPDATE**

I now notice you find the div and then look for a data-pagename on the same div so perhaps you mean

```
$('div[data-pagename="' + urlType + '"]').each(function() {
  $(this).css({'color': '#000000','z-index':'100'});
}
```

or maybe even

```
$('div[data-pagename="' + urlType + '"]').css({'color': '#000000','z-index':'100'});
```

Comment: thanks it works really well... needed to drop the .find() as you suggested... will tick when the time limit passes... cheers

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
element = $('div.mainMenuInternalTab[data-pagename="' + urlType + '"]');
```

OR

```
element = $('div.mainMenuInternalTab').filter('[data-pagename="' + urlType + '"]');
```

Using `.find(`) will search the elements which are children of the div .

But the data attribute is for the div in question. So omit it

You can also chain your selector

```
 $('div.mainMenuInternalTab').filter('[data-pagename="' + urlType + '"]')
     .css({'color': '#000000','z-index':'100'});
```

Answer (score 0):

The .find() method is applied incorrectly. Try this instead:

**HTML**

```
<div id="mainMenuInternalMyProfile" class="mainMenuInternalTab" data-pagename="example1">
    <div class="mainMenuInternalTabClickable">&nbsp;</div>
    <h4 class="mainMenuInternalTitle">MY PROFILE</h4>
    <img src="images/main-menu-divider.png" class="mainMenuBackGroundDivider" alt="Dating Internal Menu Background Divider">
    <img src="images/main-menu-selected.png" class="mainMenuBackSelected mainMenuBackSelectedOption" alt="Dating Internal Menu Selected">
</div>

<div id="mainMenuInternalMyProfile" class="mainMenuInternalTab" data-pagename="example2">
    <div class="mainMenuInternalTabClickable">&nbsp;</div>
    <h4 class="mainMenuInternalTitle">MY PROFILE</h4>
    <img src="images/main-menu-divider.png" class="mainMenuBackGroundDivider" alt="Dating Internal Menu Background Divider">
    <img src="images/main-menu-selected.png" class="mainMenuBackSelected mainMenuBackSelectedOption" alt="Dating Internal Menu Selected">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mainMenuInternalTab").each(function() {
        var _this = $(this);
        var pageName = _this.data("pagename");
        var urltype1 = "example1";
        var urltype2 = "example2";
        if (pageName === urltype1) {
            _this.css({
                "font-size": "5px"
            })
        } else if (pageName === urltype2){
           _this.css({
                "font-size": "25px"
           })
        }
    });
});
```

In my jQuery above, I'm basically running through all the instances of `.mainMenuInternalTab` and storing their `data-pagename` attribute into a variable. Following which, I just worked out a simple conditional statement that will basically assign the correct styles based on the stored data attribute's value.

You can find my working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/p57Ew/) at jsFiddle.